# copy segment from image tensor

Tags: python, image, pytorch, tensor

I have three tensors:
A - (1, 3, 256, 256)
B - (1, 3, 256, 256) - this is a white image tensor
C - (256, 256) - this is the segment tensor

For instance C would look like:

```
tensor([[ 337,  337,  337,  ...,  340,  340,  340],
        [ 337,  337,  337,  ...,  340,  340,  340],
        [ 337,  337,  337,  ...,  340,  340,  340],
        ...,
        [1022, 1022, 1022,  ..., 1010, 1010, 1010],
        [1022, 1022, 1022,  ..., 1010, 1010, 1010],
        [1022, 1022, 1022,  ..., 1010, 1010, 1010]], device='cuda:0')
```

where 37 could indicate a building etc.

Tensor C gives the location of the segment shape. What I want is to copy the same segment based on the location from tensor A onto tensor B. This would be photoshopping the segment onto a white image tensor.

This is similar to masking and I looked into mask_select (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.masked_select.html) but that only returns 1D tensor back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to select the pixels in `C`, only to mask them:

```py
select = 337  # which segment to select
select_mask = (C == select)[None, None, ...]  # create binary mask and add singleton dimensions
# this is the part where you select the right part of A
B = B * (1 - select_mask) + A * select_mask
```

Comment: I am getting `Subtraction, the `-` operator, with a bool tensor is not supported. If you are trying to invert a mask, use the `~` or `logical_not()` operator instead.` with the last line. I tried to change it to `B = B * (~select_mask) + A * select_mask` but the result was everything that's not 337

Comment: To clarify, the resulting B tensor would contain everything that's not 337 but I need only 337 instead.

Comment: nvm i was using the wrong segment for testing. After changing `1-select_mask` to `~select_mask` it worked. Thanks!